# Jenkins using wrong mail address to mail build results

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using Jenkins' ext-mail and git plugins to run the build jobs. When a commit is made to the repository build is triggered as expected, but a wrong mail address is being used to mail the build results. My .gitconfig:

```
[core]
  symlinks = false
  autocrlf = true
[user]
  name = Some One
  email = someone@domain.com
[color]
  ui = true
[merge]
  tool = bc3
[pack]
  packSizeLimit = 2g
[help]
  format = html
[diff]
  tool = bc3
[rebase]
  autosquash = true
```

But the build log indicates a different mail address picked:

```
Sending email for trigger: Success
NOT overriding default server settings, using Mailer to create session
messageContentType = text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Adding user address someone@DESKTOP-E0LPDHF.domain.local, they were not considered an excluded committer
Successfully created MimeMessage
Sending email to: someone@DESKTOP-E0LPDHF.domain.local
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Did I forget some setup?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Got it. Looks like the first made by the user was with non configured mail address at the .gitconfig file. Jenkins stored the the default address for this user ($JENKINS_HOME/users/someone/). Editing this file and restart jenkins seems to solve the issue.

Comment: No need to edit the file directly and restart Jenkins; the information is available at http://<jenkinsurl>/user/<username>/configure. Edit and Save.